# Log API calls on Android to sniff on SSL connection

Tags: android, hook

I am trying to understand the networking protocol of a specific closed-source Android App. Unfortunately, this protocol runs on top of SSL, which means that I am unable to eavesdrop on the connection using a sniffer.

Thus my question: Is it possible to log all calls including the parameters that an App makes while it is running? If this were possible, I could simply log all calls to InputStream.read() and OutputStream.write() and thereby listen to the communication.

Is there any known way to do this on a (rooted) Android device? Or do you know any other way of eavesdropping on a SSL connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you would do something like this either by altering the execution engine (ie, dalvik), or by wrapping or replacing the platform libraries of interest with logging varients.

Or you could modify the platform to make it treat all apk's as debuggable.

Another option would be to install your own SSL certificate on the device and man-in-the-middle the traffic.

Comment: `Or you could modify the platform to make it treat all apk's as debuggable.` This sounds interesting. How do you do this?

Comment: Look for the code that decides which are and aren't, or the code which acts on that information (for example, setting up the jdwp connection to adbd or not)  The package manager would be an obvious place to start looking, but might not be where the search stops.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way. Android sandboxes applications in order to prevent just this sort of thing from happening. If you do find a way, please report it to Google so they can close that hole.

Comment: On a rooted device as mentioned in the question you are not so constrained.